# NullPointer exception after trying to remove record from database with entity manager in spring app

Tags: java, spring, jpa, nullpointerexception

I am working on spring application which is managing a dogshotel buisness. In app I have two entity class - Cage and Dog (one of dog attributes is Cage). Data about dogs and cages is stored in MySQL database. In application at first we create a Dog object initializing attributes like:
name, age, race, sex, owner name, owner number. After using entity manager persist method in dogRepository class a new record appears in database:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void createDog(String name, String race, int age, String sex, String ownerFullName, int ownerPhoneNumber) {
    Dog newDog = new Dog(name, race, age, sex, ownerFullName, ownerPhoneNumber);
    em.persist(newDog);
}
```

[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPGvz.png)

Except the attributes that we enter during the creation of dog we can assign cage to it and initialize other atrributes:
int durationOfStayInDays, LocalDate startOfStayDate, LocalDate endOfStayDate, int ownerCharge.

The problem is: when dog has assigned cage I can remove it with Entity manager but when it doesn't have assigned cage I am getting NullPointerException when trying to remove it. Previously i was running the application without usage of database (records were stored in Maps inside a program) and everything was working correctly. In my code there are clases:
Dog (Entity) --> DogRepository --> DogService --> DogController. Here are code fragments of DogRepository and Dog class:

Dog class:

```
@Transactional
public void setCage(Cage cage) {
    if(cage.isFree()) {
        this.cage = cage;
        this.startOfStayDate = LocalDate.now();
        this.endOfStayDate = this.startOfStayDate.plusDays(this.durationOfStayInDays);
        cage.setFree(false);
        cage.setOccupied(true);
    }
}

public void setNullCage() {
    this.cage.setOccupied(false);
    this.cage.setFree(true);
    this.cage = null;
    this.startOfStayDate = null;
    this.endOfStayDate = null;
}
```

DogRepository:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void removeDog(Integer id) {
    Dog dog = getDogById(id);
    if (dog.getCage().isOccupied()) {
        dog.setNullCage();
    }
        em.remove(dog);

}
```

Dog Service:

```
 public void removeDog(Integer id) {
    dogRepository.removeDog(id);
}
```

Comment: Please post the exception and stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you don't check if cage is null, before checking whether it is occupied. I think, code should look like this:

```
if (dog.getCage != null && dog.getCage().isOccupied()) {
    dog.setNullCage();
}
```

Also, your method setNullCage() has the same flaw.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** If there is no `Cage` on a `Dog` then

```
if (dog.getCage().isOccupied()) {
```

will fail naturally.. you need to add `dog.getCage() != null &&`.

**2)** I would not put logic which manipulates the `Entity1` on the `Entity2`. They are two separate domains. Personally, I would use some external class for that.

**3)** You do not need to explicitly set the `Cage` to null on the `Dog` where you are deleting it. Unless you have `cascade.REMOVE` configured and you want to explicitly avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is overdoing things. Replace the below

```
if (dog.getCage().isOccupied()) {
    dog.setNullCage();
}
```

with

```
dog.setNullCage();
```

and change `setNullCage` to

```
public void setNullCage() {
     this.cage = null;
}
```

A better name for `setNullCage` could be `clearCage` or `removeCage`